# Injecting into a different project/assembly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, structuremap, httpcontext, simple-injector

I've been at this subject for hours now, so I decided to write and ask for some help.

There are many answers already on this forum that I can identify as being solutions to my problem, but I'm just not able to connect all the dots inside my head; and I'm not getting it done.

I'm trying to change injector on a big MVC application, from StructureMap to SimpleInjector.

I need to correctly pass the current user of the HttpContext to another project on the same solution holding all the repositories and the DBContext so it can be used/written when I do some CRUD operations.

I clearly didn't understand how StructureMap was wired; I found it complicated. I had this on the MVC project (can provide more info, because there a dozen of classes using StructureMap):

```
public class GlobalRegistry : StructureMap.Registry
{
    public GlobalRegistry()
    {
        For<INotificationRepository>().Use<NotificationRepository>();
        ...
```

and on the repositories project/class:

```
public class NotificationRepository : BaseRepository,INotificationRepository
{
    public NotificationRepository(string userContext) : base(userContext) { }
```

(...by magic...) the constructor would take userContext parameter to use later within the called method.

After replacement with SimpleInjector, I don't understand how this parameter gets injected.

For testing purposes, this works:

```
container.Register<INotificationRepository>(() => new NotificationRepository("username"), 
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

I read that I'm not supposed to inject `HttpContext` in the constructor, as it is a runtime variable and I understand why.

Next I tried a `IUserContextFactory`, but it didn't work either.

On the same MVC project, I have his class:

```
public static class ObjectFactory
{
    private static SimpleInjector.Container _container;

    public static void SetContainer(Container container)
    {
        ObjectFactory._container = container;
    }

    public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : class
    {
        return _container.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

I'm using this class to store the container after `container.Verify();`

```
ObjectFactory.SetContainer(container);
```

On any MVC controller I use it like this:

```
IUserContext ctxUser = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUserContext>();
```

I've also tried something like the following on the repository throughout my attempts, but I always end up with a null `UserName`.

```
public NotificationRepository(IUserContext userContext) : base(userContext) { }
```

(common interface between MVC project and the repository project)

```
public interface IUserContext
{
    string Username { get; set; }
}
```

More important than knowing the solution, I would like to understand how the solution works and overcome the difficulty I've been having for the past few hours trying to understand and solve this.

Comment: Well, there should also be a registration for the context in `StructureMap`, convert that to the other syntax too. By the way, this `Lifestyle.Singleton` doesn't look good.

Comment: I don't get what your actual problem is, where you're stuck and what it is you are trying to understand.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, did not find a context on StructureMap being injected.
When the user logs in it stays the same until it logs out, where I'm i missing something? Multiple users!?

Comment: @Steven, i was hoping to get a answer from you, you are the constant on all #simple-injector tab. My bad, i don't know how to explain/express my self, that is the problem. Already solved my problem. Not sure if i completely understand my own solution. I question so many times... me as a programmer... ohh well, this thread should be deleted it's confusing.

Comment: The context must have been registered. How else would the IoC container know how to inject it into a repository? (Which is "magic" for you, but is nothing but configuration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a run-time primitive value as a parameter to the constructor is not directly available in Simple Inject. Instead you can inject a component that allows you to get that value at run-time, so your approach with `IUserContext` seems the good way to go, it should work. Modify your class to add that component in your constructor, instead of the `userName` string. Register the new component and let you container inject it automatically when calling the constructor.

A sample implementation:

```
class HttpSessionUserContext : IUserContext 
{
    //Your specific implementation of getting the user name from your context
    public string CurrentUserName => (string)HttpContext.Session["userName"];
}
```

The registration:

```
container.Register<IUserContext, HttpSessionUserContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<INotificationRepository, NotificationRepository> (Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

[Here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) you have more info about the reason why passing primitive run-time parameters to the constructors is not implemented in Simple Inject.

About Lifestyle scopes: You probably shouldn't use `Lifestyle.Singleton` as your scope for this component, as it would get instantiated only once and reused as a singleton. In web apps you usually want to apply a Per-HttpRequest scope. You can do it like this: after creating your container define its default scope as `WebRequestLifestyle`, or `WebApiRequestLifestyle`:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
```

And then when you register your components use the value `Lifestyle.Scoped`, which will apply the default scoped Lifestyle:

```
container.Register<SomeInterface, SomeClass>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

**Edit:** as per [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven)'s comment, in this case it would be better registering `HttpSessionUserContext` as `Singleton`, because it is stateless. In general, `Singleton` has a better performance because it is only instantiated once and shared, but be careful with components that are not stateless or have dependencies to other components.

Also, make sure that you registered your MVC controllers and assigned the instance of your container to your MVC `DependencyResolver`. This is what really enables the automatic resolving and injection of the parameters in the constructors in the controllers. I guess you did this in your `Application_Start` event handler.

```
container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
container.Verify();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
        new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

Comment: I agree with your answer Diana, thank you for your help.
I'm injecting IUserContext on the LoginControler and then getting username after valid user login, that will remain the same until logout, but not might not seeing things right on this situation.

Comment: Since the `HttpSessionUserContext` class is stateless, it can be registered as singleton and my advise would therefore be to actually register it as singleton. There's no harm in doing that. As a matter of fact, I consider it a good practice to have as much singleton registrations as possible.

Comment: @Steven You are right, it will be better like that, better performance. I use to register things as per-request just as a conservative approach, if performance is not critical, but singleton registration is more efficient. Just be careful with components that are not stateless, or have dependencies to other components.

Comment: @Diana in the case a singleton component has dependencies, Simple Injector will *always* check for you whether there are lifestyle mismatches. If that component depends on a scoped or transient, Simple Injector will throw an exception.

Comment: @Steven OK, thanks, I was thinking more like the component having a method that modifies data somewhere or does non-thread-safe things with other components that might be Singletons or not. I had problems with that in the past (probably because a bad implementation and a misunderstanding about how scopes work).